# Appending an anchor to every list item in an unordered list - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm struggling to get my syntax correct to correctly append an anchor inside a list item with the structure I'm working with.

The structure that I have to append into is below;

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
<ul class="q_circles_holder five_columns no_line">
   <li class="q_circle_outer">
     <a href="/the-potential-centre" target="_self">
        <img src="/test.img">
     </a>
     <div class="q_circle_text_holder">
        <h3 class="q_circle_title" style="">The Header Text</h3>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I need to create a function that will loop through every list item inside the un-ordered list and place an anchor link (using the already stated href ) So ideally my desired output would then read -

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
 <ul class="q_circles_holder five_columns no_line">
   <li class="q_circle_outer">
     <a href="/the-potential-centre" target="_self">
        <img src="/test.img">
     </a>
     <div class="q_circle_text_holder">
        <h3 class="q_circle_title" style="">The Header Text</h3>
        <a href="/the-potential-centre" target="_self">Learn More</a> 
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have this currently, but its not working correctly

NOT WORKING CODE -

```
$('.q_circles_holder').find('li').each(function(idx) {
    var $this = $(this),
        str = '<a class="learn-more" target="_self" href="' + $this.find('a').attr('href') + '">Learn More</a>';
    $this.append(str);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.q_circles_holder').find('li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var href = $this.find('a:eq(0)').attr('href');
  $this.find('h3').after("<a href='"+href+"' target='_self'>Learn More</a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="q_circles_holder five_columns no_line">
   <li class="q_circle_outer">
     <a href="/the-potential-centre" target="_self">
        <img src="/test.img">
     </a>
     <div class="q_circle_text_holder">
        <h3 class="q_circle_title" style="">The Header Text</h3>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$this.append(str)` with `$this.find('.q_circle_text_holder').append(str)`

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.  Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sjpszy4e/.

Javascript

```
$('.q_circles_holder').find('li').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<a class="learn-more" target="_self" href="' + $(this).find('a').attr('href') + '">Learn More</a>');
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="q_circles_holder five_columns no_line">
   <li class="q_circle_outer">
     <a href="/the-potential-centre" target="_self">
        <img src="/test.img">
     </a>
     <div class="q_circle_text_holder">
        <h3 class="q_circle_title" style="">The Header Text</h3>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="q_circle_outer">
     <a href="/the-potential-centre2" target="_self">
        <img src="/test.img">
     </a>
     <div class="q_circle_text_holder">
        <h3 class="q_circle_title" style="">The Header Text 2</h3>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```